# Issues installing jfrog container registry via docker image

Tags: docker, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

Im currently trying to install the Jfrog container registry via the docker image and it errors just as it reaches the ui after setup. My process of installing is as follows

```
docker pull docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-jcr:latest
docker run --name artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-jcr:latest
```

I navigate to `localhost:8081/artifactory` and after the setup image it redirects to `localhost:8082/ui/` and shows page not found. Im not sure why the port changes and I have looked at the documentation for installing and there isnt anything about the port change. changing the port back to 8081 just shows a HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.

Im on docker for windows, looking to test this out. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory internal architecture has changed, and there are separate micro services for Artifactory and its UI. This is done via the JFrog router, which listens on port **8082**.

If you follow [the Docker installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation) documentation, you can see you need to also expose port **8082**.

```
docker run --name artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-jcr:latest
```

You can also drop the port 8081 and stick to 8082 only. 8081 allows for direct access to Artifactory (bypassing the jfrog router) for better performance on high load systems.

Comment: what is the correct way/URL to access the registry using docker login when it's exposed on localhost?

Comment: It depends on the setup you have. Assuming you are using the latest version - follow https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-PushingandPullingImages